# Xcode - get black programming screen

Tags: xcode, swift

Forgive my ignorance, but how do you get the programming and console screens to black, rather than white background?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692817/how-to-theme-the-entire-xcode-ide-to-light-on-dark and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260226/about-xcode-console-text-color-and-background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Xcode open navigate to the menu bar. Xcode > Preferences... and open Fonts & Colors.

Try changing your setting from Default to Dusk.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in preferences, as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-fonts_and_colors_preferences_help/Recipe.html). This can be done from Xcode > Preferences > Fonts and Colors. Here you can switch your color profile, change the background of the default one, or add one and change it there.

Comment: Instead of only refering into a link you must give specific instructions, and use the reference to complement your answer.